# А слово...

Tags: лексика

А слово пусть может быть предлогом?

Comment: Слово "пусть", прежде всего, пишется в кавычках в данном случае. И хоть немного думайте хоть чем-то, когда ставите теги.

Comment: $$@Fuchoin Kazuki!$$
Грубовато. А вдруг @Koldik больше не появится со следующим вопросом - побоится, а? Разгоним всех сомневающихся и что будем делать без них? Скучно будет. Таким способом и малышей от чтения можно отвадить. А у нас задача - привлечь, научить!

Comment: Участникам неоднократно напоминались правила оформления своих вопросов. Надо действовать по правилам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет. Предлог образует падежную форму существительного: стол, около стола, у стола, за столом, между столами, о столах и т.д. Слово "пусть" такую роль выполнять не может. Обычно это формообразующая частица. Образует повелительное наклонение глагола: пусть они уйдут.

Answer (score 0):

> А слово пусть может быть предлогом?

Надо попытаться составить с нам словосочетание:)))